# Endeca Baseline update failed with Logserver issue

Tags: endeca

baseline_update.sh job is failing with logserver issue.
Logserver log has following message
"LogServer started in non-SSL mode"

I tried restarting PlatformServices

Comment: Have you configured application to use SSL? Maybe check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E66320_01/common.11-2/EndecaSecurity/html/csec_ssl_logdgraphforge.xmlconcept_83EF155D887D43A6A5053C7C6DC92B4B.html

Comment: Also is there a specific exception thrown? Can you provide the complete output of the script?